# R "points" function misaligned with map

Tags: r, plot, maps

The points() function will not properly overlay the coordinates onto a map generated with base plot, even though the coordinates all match up.

misaligned map is shown below.

links to 2 simple lists of coordinates:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1m0EgTw_XJ25x5r_IrsSXow-WFwFBLVXm?usp=sharing
(for "main", separator is a semicolon)

Thank you so much for your help, I have been trying to fix this for hours!

I have tried manually specifying the coordinate boundaries but that does not change the issue.

```
plot(main,col=1,main="",
     xlim = c(-124.48,-114.13), ylim = c(32.53,42.01),
)

points(plantcoords)
```

misaligned plot:

[image: MAP]

as you can see, the points do not properly line up with the map, even though the range of the coordinates of the points is within the limits of the map.

Comment: What makes you certain that the points are actually properly aligned with the image (and the problem is with `points`)? (BTW: I suggest you provide a better data source than your `main.csv`, I don't want to spend the time trying to read the CSV and parse the R-code you have in each cell to properly create another R object. Perhaps you can provide a json file of your data instead of a CSV?)

Comment: Maps normally have the lat-long coordinates passed through a projection function.  You'll need to figure out which projection was used in your map, and transform the points in the same way.